# why java returns java.util.LinkedHashMap when ... complex

Tags: java, list, generics, collections, casting

my code is as below...

```
@ResponseBody 
@RequestMapping(value ="/updateAll", method=RequestMethod.POST)  
public JSONObject update( @RequestBody List<T> list){ 
    try{
        T entity = list.get(0);
        System.out.println(entity.getClass());
        dbService.update(entityName + ".update", list);
        return jsonResult(null, null, null, 0);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return jsonResult(null, null, ex, 0);
    }
}
```

It returns an proper object name when I get only one entity through @RequestBody, but the code above returns java.util.LinkedHashMap which i cannot use the merit of parameterClass in iBatis.
(sorry for my poor english... )

I cast again the list to T , but still it returns LinkedHashMap.

isn't the code [ T entity = list.get(0); ] means it recognize the list as the collection of object T ?

```
@ResponseBody 
@RequestMapping(value ="/updateAll", method=RequestMethod.POST)  
public JSONObject update( @RequestBody T entity){ 
    try{
        System.out.println(entity.getClass());
        dbService.update(entityName + ".update", entity);
        return jsonResult(null, null, null, 0);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return jsonResult(null, null, ex, 0);
    }
}
```

This prints the entity name exactly without any problem.

Can anybody explain me why this happen? where I can learn more about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 /**
     * Returns the runtime class of this {@code Object}. The returned
     * {@code Class} object is the object that is locked by {@code
     * static synchronized} methods of the represented class.
     *
     * <p><b>The actual result type is {@code Class<? extends |X|>}
     * where {@code |X|} is the erasure of the static type of the
     * expression on which {@code getClass} is called.</b> For
     * example, no cast is required in this code fragment:</p>
     *
     * <p>
public final native Class<?> getClass();
```

It doesn't matter what reference type is . Method `getClass()` returns `runtime class`.